# NSDateComponents: How to replace deprecated NSWeekCalendarUnit to calc week start date?

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents

I am currently updating an old iOS App that uses `NSDateComponents` to calculate the start date of the week a given `NSDate` is in:

```
NSDate* someDate = [MyDateFactory dateFromDay:31 month:8 year:2017];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit) fromDate:someDate];

// For 2017-08-31 comps is now year=2017, week (obsolete)=35

comps.calendar = calendar;
NSDate* weekStartDate = [comps date];

// weekStartDate = 2017-08-27
```

This works fine, but `NSYearCalendarUnit` and `NSWeekCalendarUnit` are both deprecated. Replacing `NSYearCalendarUnit` with the new `NSCalendarUnitYear` is no problem. But what it the correct replacemtn for `NSWeekCalendarUnit`.

It seems that `NSWeekCalendarUnit` returns the same value (week of year) as the new `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear`. **But this does not result in the same `weekStartDate`:**

```
// ... same as above. Now use new enum values
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear) fromDate:someDate];

// For 2017-08-31 comps is now year=2017, week of year=35 <== Same es above

comps.calendar = calendar;
NSDate* weekStartDate = [comps date];

// weekStartDate = 2017-01-01
```

So using `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` returns the same week value (week 35), but it seems that this value is not considered when calculating the date from the the `NSDateComponents` object. 2017-01-01 is obviously not the date week 35 starts at in 2017.

So, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use other methods of `NSCalendar` instead.

To get the day on which weeks start, use `calendar.firstWeekday`.

Then put this into some date components:

```
NSDateComponents *search = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
search.weekDay = calendar.firstWeekday;
```

Now you can use the calendar to find the previous date which matches the components:

```
NSDate *weekStart = [calendar nextDateAfterDate: someDate matchingComponents: search options: NSCalendarSearchBackwards];
```